# Email sender is incorrect

Tags: mern, nodemailer

I'm trying to send a message to the owner of a listing but recipient is getting the email from my gmail account and not of the user that is contacting the owner. It's using 'process.env.EMAIL_USER' rather than the currentUserEmail. Maybe it's using the email from process.env.EMAIL_USER but I thought that's to make setup so that we can send emails

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';

export default function Contact({listing}) {
    const {currentUser} = useSelector((state) => state.user);
    const currentUserEmail = currentUser.email;
    const [landlord, setLandlord] = useState(null);
    const [message, setMessage] = useState('');
    
    const onChange = (e) => {
        setMessage(e.target.value);
    }
    
    const sendEmail = async () => {
        try {
            const res = await fetch('/api/contact/send-email', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    from: currentUserEmail,
                    to: landlord.email,
                    subject: `Regarding ${listing.name}`,
                    text: message,
                })
            });
            if (!res.ok) {
                throw new Error('Failed to send email');
            }
            alert('Email sent successfully');
            const data = await res.json();
            console.log(data);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    
    }

    useEffect(()=>{
        const fetchLandlord = async () => {
            try {
                const res = await fetch(`/api/user/${listing.userRef}`);
                const data = await res.json();
                setLandlord(data);
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        }
        fetchLandlord();
    }, [listing.userRef])
  return (
    <>
        {landlord && (
            <div className='flex flex-col gap-2'>
                <p>Contact <span className='font-semibold'>{landlord.username}</span> for <span className='font-semibold'>{listing.name.toLowerCase()}</span></p>
                <textarea name="message" id="message" rows="2" value={message} onChange={onChange} placeholder='Enter your message here...' className='w-full border p-3 rounded-lg '></textarea>
                <button onClick={sendEmail} className='bg-slate-700 text-white text-center p-3 rounded-lg uppercase hover:opacity-95'>
                    Send Message
                </button>
            </div>
        )}
    </>
  )
}

This is the controller:
import nodemailer from 'nodemailer';
import dotenv from "dotenv";

dotenv.config();

export const sendEmail = async (req, res, next) => {
    const { from, to, subject, text } = req.body;
    try {
        const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
            service: 'gmail',
            auth: {
                user: process.env.EMAIL_USER,
                pass: process.env.EMAIL_PASS
            }
        });        
        const mailOptions = {
            from: from,
            to: to,
            subject: subject,
            text: text
        };
        await transporter.sendMail(mailOptions);
        res.status(200).json({ success: true, message: "Email send successfully." });
    } catch (error) {
        next(error);
    }
};
```